# Changed our site IP address, now can't login to EE

Tags: admin.php

We moved our site to a new server, have a new IP address. Now, when I go to www.nameofthesite.com/admin.php and log in, I get a blank screen.

Do I need to change the IP somewhere in the EE config files?

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely getting a 500 error if you are getting a blank screen while trying to log in. This will have nothing to do with your IP address, this is a fatal PHP error occurring.

In order to determine what is going wrong, you need to turn error reporting on.

https://docs.expressionengine.com/v3/general/system_configuration_overrides.html#debug

Set this value in your config.php file, which either lives in

`EE2: {web_root}/system/expressionengine/config/config.php`

or

`EE3 & EE4: {web_root}/system/user/config/config.php`

Note that when you set this value, you must set it to `2` to see what error is showing after you attempt to log in. Also note that if the front end of your website has suppressed warnings, they **will** start showing up while the debug override is set, likely breaking some pages on the front end of your site.

If you just moved from one server to another, a common error you will see is that you are missing some vital PHP module, such as `php-mbyte`, for EE. The solution is to install the missing PHP module and restart Apache. Another common error is that you will be missing some files from when you transferred from one server to another; EE fails if it is missing any third-party files usually.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you so much for the answer. I appreciate it. I was able to work with Ellis Labs and get it working again. There was an error in one of the config files.